# javascript variable number greater than number by how many?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function to validate if a number is greater than another number but what I want to know I want to know is by how much. So 24 is > 10 but I want to know by how much 14.

```
if(ranNum > numbered){
            alert("ranNum is greater than your number");
          }else if(ranNum < numbered){
            alert("ranNum is less then your number");
          }else if(ranNum === numbered){
            alert("match");
          }else{
            alert("try again");
          }
```

Comment: Subtraction (`-` operator).

Comment: Can I do both less then and greater then the use the - operator?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a diff variable by subtracting the two numbers and adding it to the alert.

```
Var diff = Math.abs (ranNum - numbered);
if(ranNum > numbered) {
    alert("ranNum is greater than your number by: " + diff);
}
else if(ranNum < numbered) {
     alert("ranNum is less then your number by: " + diff);
 }
else if(ranNum === numbered) {
    alert("match");
}
else{
    alert("try again");
}
```